# npm error: `lock-verify` throws an error on CI when running `npm ci`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-ci

Locally, both `npm install` and `npm ci` runs successfully. However, on CI , `npm ci` breaks with the error `npm ERR! Cannot read property '@babel/runtime' of undefined`. When I check the logs, it points to an error with lock-verify, even though on npmjs.com it presents lock-verify as deprecated for npm v7 onwards, and I'm using npm 9.3.1.
When running lock-verify locally, I get the same error as the one on CI:

```
npx lock-verify
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '@babel/runtime')
    at /Users/aprilgoncalves/workspace/excelsior/frontend/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:27:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/aprilgoncalves/workspace/excelsior/frontend/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:25:25
```

I have re-generated `package-lock.json` may times, and it doesn't seem to fix this issue. Any thoughts on how to solve this issue?